# Need help converting Pinescript v2 to v4 conversion

Tags: pine-script

I have been trying to convert this to v4 but having a lot of issues, particularly with errors related to passing arguments into the plot function for dl. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have looked at the V3 conversion guide. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
study(title="EIT", shorttitle="EIT", overlay=true, precision=3)
src=input(hl2, title="Source")
a= input(0.07, title="Alpha", step=0.01) 
fr=input(false, title="Fill Trend Region")
ebc=input(false, title="Enable barcolors")
hr=input(false, title="Hide Ribbon")
it=0.0
it:=(a-((a*a)/4.0))*src+0.5*a*a*src[1]-(a-0.75*a*a)*src[2]+2*(1-a )*nz(it[1], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))-(1-a )*(1-a )*nz(it[2], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))
lag=2.0*it-nz(it[2])
dl=0.0
dl:=plot(fr and (not hr)?(it>lag?lag:it):na, color=gray, style=circles, linewidth=0, title="Dummy")
itl=plot(hr?na:it, color=fr?gray:red, linewidth=1, title="Trend")
ll=plot(hr?na:lag, color=fr?gray:blue, linewidth=1, title="Trigger")
fill(dl, ll, green, title="UpTrend", transp=70)
fill(dl, itl, red, title="DownTrend", transp=70)
bc=not ebc?na:(it>lag?red:lime)
barcolor(bc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
//@version=4
study(title="EIT", shorttitle="EIT", overlay=true, precision=3)

src = input(hl2, title="Source")
a   = input(0.07, title="Alpha", step=0.01) 
fr  = input(false, title="Fill Trend Region")
ebc = input(false, title="Enable barcolors")
hr  = input(false, title="Hide Ribbon")

var float it = 0.0

it := (a-((a*a)/4.0))*src+0.5*a*a*src[1]-(a-0.75*a*a)*src[2]+2*(1-a )*nz(it[1], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))-(1-a )*(1-a )*nz(it[2], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))
lag = 2.0*it-nz(it[2])

dl  = plot(fr and (not hr)?(it>lag?lag:it):na, color=color.gray, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0, title="Dummy")
itl = plot(hr?na:it, color=fr?color.gray:color.red, linewidth=1, title="Trend")
ll  = plot(hr?na:lag, color=fr?color.gray:color.blue, linewidth=1, title="Trigger")

fill(dl, ll, color.green, title="UpTrend", transp=70)
fill(dl, itl, color.red, title="DownTrend", transp=70)

bc = not ebc?na:(it>lag?color.red:color.lime)
barcolor(bc)
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)